# TCP connections bottleneck over the internet(SSL handshakes)

Tags: multithreading, sockets, tcp, network-programming, multiprocessing

I've got up some server-client pair that uses epoll, 5 ips with about 100 ports to listen on each.The system is some spawning processes that spawn about 100 server daemons and about 100 connection_maker daemons.

This build can take up to 3-4000 SSL handshakes per second on LAN and only 40 over the internet(under 200ms round-trip), i've tried a lot of things but i just can't see where the bottleneck is. Any hint could be useful(The socket FDs are blocking now but making them nonblocking helps nothing since the degree of parallelism is way bigger than 40 connections per second anyway).

Comment: I'm assuming your LAN round-trips are < 1ms?

Comment: i see where you're getting but what can be done? nonblocking the listen sockets does not help much

Comment: It's difficult to tell without some code and without profiling. You're obviously burning time somewhere.

Comment: any hints about profiling? the action taking place is something like --> SSLconnect-SSLaccept + a change of hellos<-(inside a thread) and that is it.. if you suspect a part of the code being involved i'd gladly show you it:)

Comment: Are you using `epoll()` with the level-triggered notification or the edge-triggered one ?

Comment: it is level-triggered right now.. but i don't think it has an impact since there are like 5 sockets that each(1 per server process) epoll handles.

Answer (score 0):

Increment your "ulimit" value , if you are using linux.

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: there are quite a few ulimit values and i've played around with some so please be more specific.